# How to run Expdp from a remote machine?

Tags: oracle

I would like to run Expdp from a remote machine that doesn't have oracle.

I tried :

```
expdp *******/*******@ipadress:1521/XE directory=DumpDirectory dumpfile=MySchema.dmp logfile=MySchema.log SCHEMAS = MySchema
```

But I'm getting the error :

```
UDE-12560: operation generated ORACLE error 12560
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

My database is running properly and I can access it from SQL Developer.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to `set ORACLE_SID=sid_of_the_remote_database` at the command prompt?

Comment: You say your machine "doesn't have oracle", but the fact that you got the error you did shows you have _something_ of oracle, if not a database.  What did you discover when you googled "ORA-12560"?  Show us the entry for 'XE' in the tnsnames.ora of the machine from which you are trying to execute expdp, and the output of 'lsnrctl status' on the machine where the database lives.  No screen shots, COpy and paste the text from the command prompt, updateing your question with the results, and formatting the text as code.